# Testing Performance on SSIS Packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, performance-testing

I'm trying to understand how much a performance cost a certain SSIS package has.

It's something which will be scheduled to run several times a day. Through SQL Server Management Studio, I can run a report which tells me that the package runs in about 2 seconds, however I'm wondering if I can test the computational cost of the package in order to compare it with a query.

For example, if I run `SELECT * FROM tbl` and select "Include Live Query Statistics", I can see the estimated CPU cost and I/O cost of the query. Is there a way to check the CPU and I/O cost of an SSIS package?

Comment: Are you using the SSISDB for deployment?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Ask your DBA to monitor resources while it's running.